# How to write a Google Doc type rich text editor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I need to write a rich text editor similar to Google Doc. Does anyone know any samples of similar projects? What technologies will I need? and what process is involved?

Comment: Is there a reason why you NEED to create your own? Instead of downloading one?

Comment: because I need to customize it

Comment: What prevents you from customising one of the many open-source existing rich text editors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out ckEditor or TinyMCE for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would take an existing text-editing tool and customize it from there.  All the code is there for your tweaking.  I still haven't found an web-based RTE that I'm in love with, but the [YUI 2 rich text editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) would have to be my recommendation.  It has a simple and clean interface if you're looking for something Google Doc-ish.